# C++: construction and destruction of static inner class instance in outer class

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and learning the nested classes and static class member of C++, I write the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Outter
{
public:
    Outter() {
        //get();
        cout << "construct Outter" << endl;
    }
    ~Outter() {
        cout << "destruct Outter" << endl;
    }
private:
    class Inner
    {
    public:
        Inner() {
            cout << "construct Inner" << endl;
        }
        ~Inner() {
            cout << "destruct Inner" << endl;
        }
    };
    //Inner get() {
    //    return i;
    //}
    static Inner i;
};

int main() {
    Outter o;
    return 0;
}
```

I make a inner class and a static instance of inner class in outter class. When I run this code without `get()` function, the result output is:

```
construct Outter
destruct Outter
```

Then I remove the comment of `get()` function and call it in `Outter()`, I rerun the program, the output become:

```
destruct Inner
construct Outter
destruct Outter
```

I am confused with this result because in my understand there should be a `construct Inner` before `destruct Inner` and `destruct Inner` should after `destruct Outter`. Can someone explain what happens here?

Comment: I have my doubts as to whether the shown code would even compile and link, since the static class member is never defined, only declared.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It [does](https://godbolt.org/z/fxDsFp).

Comment: Ah, I see why it compiles. It compiles because [the shown program makes demons fly out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). The missing constructor call is from the copy constructor that copies a non-existent object, hence no constructor call, and the destructor call is from the temporary being destroyed. The shown code is still ill-formed, but the compiler is not required to produce an error message in this edge case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is not as you expect because `Inner i;` is already constructed when you call `get`.

What happens is the following:
 1. In `get` you get a static instance to `i`, which is a copy operation, no default construction is going here.
 3. You return a temporary *copied* `Inner` object, which gets immediately destructed, hence `destruct Inner`.

The `Outer`, I suppose, is self-evident. You construct it and it is destructed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be correct. `i` is not defined anywhere, and if it were, the constructor should be called.

Comment: I assumed that this is an incomplete code snippet and with that assumpion I explained why the OP gets the unintuitive output.

Comment: Your answer is slightly incorrect. `static Inner` is never constructed, because it does not exist anywhere. You can't construct something that does not exist.

Comment: The OP's code, btw, compiles with g++ 10 and even outputs the same thing as asked in the question.

Comment: That's because both compilers completely optimize away the reference to the non-declared object, hence no link failure. If the default copy constructor formally references the object being copied (even though nothing is ever formally copied from it) there would be a link failure.

Comment: I understand what you mean, I want to know whether there is a way to initialize such `static Inner i`.

Comment: It's a non-constexpr variable, so you would need to define it in some compilation unit, which means that you would need to refer to `Outter::Inner`, and the nested class `Inner` is private, and types have the same access controls as variables, which means that straighforward `Outter::Inner i = Outter::Inner();` will not work. You could probably concoct some static friend initializer, but this sounds shady at best. It's really a question if `Inner` must absolutely be private here.